# Can't connect to encrypted wireless networks via gui

Tags: release-hera, wifi

When I try to connect to an encrypted wifi via the gui I get an error message that says "This wireless network could not be connected to." (see screenshot below).

[image]

I'm not being asked for the wifi password when I click to connect to the encrypted network. If I open up the network settings to connect to a network I don't get the error message but I'm also not being asked for a password and can't connect to the encrypted network. With open (unencrypted) wifis I don't have these problems and everything works fine.

If I use network manager cli I'm able to connect to encrypted networks just fine. Any idea what the gui related problem might be?

Comment: Can you please try using `sudo nmtui` to remove the saved connection (nmtui is a small terminal app to easily edit saved wifi connections? My bet is on a wrong password saved for that wifi acces point

Comment: Thanks for your hint. This is a pretty helpful tool. Unfortunately your suggestion did not solve my problem. It was the first time I tried to connect to this wifi  when I got the error (never was asked for a pw). The wifi is still added to the connections in the nmtui tool. I did delete the wifi connection in the tool but the error persists. I also deleted another wifi connection where I didn't had this problem when I first connected to it and tried to reconnect via the gui - I now got the same problem with the network that worked fine previously. Seems like I messed something up somewhere ...